# Sublime Text 2 and R

Tags: r, sublimetext2

I am trying to use Sublime Text 2 as an interface to the statistics software R [update/edit: Solved!].

On Windows, I have tried the following:

1. Installed R Tools. Turned out to be for Macintosh 64 only.
2. Tried to program custom build file. Failed: no output returned.

   ```
   {
   "cmd": "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.9.2/bin/R.exe --no-save $File"
   }
   ```
3. Installed SublimeREPL. Failed: R menu option disabled...
4. [update/edit] Tried this (see wuub's reply):

   ```
   {
       "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.9.2\\bin"}  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open SublimeREPL's user settings like this: `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User`

there set default_extend_path to point to your R installation:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.14.2\\bin\\i386"}  
}
```

Running `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> R` should launch REPL as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a try, saved, and restarted Sublime text 2. However, all items are still greyed out in the Sublime REPLmenu. I cannot run R at all.

Comment: Try Tools -> Command Palette and type "SublimeREPL: R". I cannot think of anything that would cause menu items to be disabled, it seems something is wrong with your ST2 installation.

Comment: Install seems to be corrupt. Cannot find the command in the Command Palette.

Comment: Great. There are still some unsolved problems with SublimeREPL & R (see: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5802) but at least for some it seems to be usable.

Answer (score 2):

For windows system you can add a new build for R (Tools -> Build System -> New Build System) and put the following lines. Modify the path according to your R installation directory.

```
{"cmd": ["Rscript.exe", "$file"],
"path": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\x64\\",
"selector": "source.r"}
```

You can execute the entire file by pressing ctrl+B instead of starting SublimeREPL.

Answer (score 1):

The build system value needs to be an array so you want;

```
{
  "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/R/R-2.9.2/bin/R.exe", "--no-save", "$File"]
}
```

https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/build-systems.html#file-format

Answer (score 0):

For linux users, take a look:

[Sublime Text 2 R build System](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78181/sublime-text-2-r-build-system-source-file-send-selection-to-interactive-sessio)

It supports multi selection and interactive R sessions.

Comment: This build uses xsel and xdotool. Autohotkey (AHK) could be an alternative for windows users.

Comment: Have you done the configuration steps? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732597/sublimetext-and-r-setting-current-file-directory/29733166#29733166