# SublimeText and R: Setting Current File Directory

Tags: r, sublimetext2

I have just started to use Sublime Text 2 to edit/write R codes and have installed the SublimeREPL package to execute R code within the editor.  When I write a new R script it fails to read files in the SAME directory with the error:

```
Error in file(file, “rt”) : cannot open the connection
```

I checked `getwd()` and it shows `C:/windows/system32` which is probably the directory where sublime text is installed.

Is there a way to set the current working directory to the location of the current file. This can be easily done in RStudio with `Session > setwd > source file location`.

I can use the full path of the data file as a workaround, but I think that is not a convenient solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check again whether the settings of SUBLIMERepl are configured correctly :

```
Open Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - Default
```

copy all the text

then open `Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeREPL > Settings - User`

overwrite and paste the text there

Restart Sublime

When I then open `tools > SublimeREPL > R`, I can `setwd()` as usual. 
The default `getwd()` returned "`/`" for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I did this and now when I open SublimeREPL > R and do getwd() it gives me the working directory of the last .R script that was highlighted before opening SublimeREPL.  However, if I now highlight code from a different .R script, SublimeREPL still gives me the old working directory. Is it possible to have a setting in SublimeREPL that changes the getwd() to the current active code's location and not the location that was current when SublimeREPL > R was invoked?

Comment: I don't think so. Highlighting is not execution. You will have to use setwd(). You can consider switching back to RStudio, where Ctrl+Shift+H is the shortcut for changing working directory. By the way, consider accepting the answer above, if it helped.